# How would I be able to call the face value of the object from the deck?

Tags: python, list, object

I haven't worked with Python in a while, so I'm kind of struggling. I want to be able to call the face value of the card in the deck, but when I call it there is no return, it's just blank.

```py
import random

def guessFaceOnly():
    randNum=random.randint(0,len(face)-1)
    print("\nFace Guess: " +face[randNum])
    print("Pulled Cards Face: "+ deck[51].face)
def guessSuitOnly():
    print("ok")
def guessFaceAndSuit():
    print("J")
def menu():
    print("To play the game choose one of the following:\n1: To guess the face value only.\n2: To guess the suit value only.\n3: To guess the both the face and suit.\n9: To end the game.\n")
    
class Card:
    def __init__(c, suit, face):
        c.suit=""
        c.face=""
face = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five","Six", "Seven", "Eight","Nine", "Ten","Jack", "Queen", "King"]
suit = ["Spade", "Club", "Diamond", "Heart"]
deck = []

for i in range(0,13):
    for j in range(0,4):
        newCard=Card(suit[j], face[i])
        deck.append(newCard)
        
i=0
while i!=9:
    menu()
    random.shuffle(deck)
    choice = input()
    if(choice=="1"):
        guessFaceOnly()
    elif(choice=="2"):
        guessSuitOnly()
    elif(choice=="3"):
        guessFaceAndSuit()
    elif(choice=="9"):
        break
```

[image]

Comment: Every `Card` you create has a suit of "", and a face of "".  Those two assignments are the only thing your `.__init__()` method is doing; the parameters you pass to it are not being used for anything.

Comment: @jasonharper ok that was stupid of me. So now when I try to call the face it passes me an error saying string object is not callable even though im passing it as a string and I am printing it as a string. ```python def guessFaceOnly():
    randNum=random.randint(0,len(face)-1)
    print("\nFace Guess: " +face[randNum])
    print("Pulled Cards Face: "+ str(call_face(deck[51])))
def call_face(obj):
    return obj.face()```

Answer (score 0):

In the card constructor, you're setting `suit` and `face` to empty string. Instead you need to pass the values like so:

```
    def __init__(c, suit, face):
        c.suit=suit
        c.face=face
```

Comment: Thank you I fixed that issue shortly after noticing it. However when I try to call the face value I am passed with an error message saying str object is not callable.

Comment: Are you trying to use face as a function? Try to remove the parenthesis, `card.face` instead of `card.face()`

Comment: yep youre right that works. thank you my man.